# Problem using Type 1 fonts with XeTeX and TeX Live 2022

Tags: xetex, fontspec, type1, texlive2022

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which brought me *TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian* and *xdvipdfmx Version 20210609*. Now I am having troubles with using fonts from the Aurical package with XeTeX and fontspec. Aurical is a collection of three really nice handwritten fonts in Type 1 format.

More precisely, when I try to compile the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\begin{document}

\fontspec{JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant.pfb}[Path = /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/, Scale = 2]

ABCDEFG

\end{document}
```

running `xelatex --no-pdf` followed by `xdvipdf --vv` I receive this output from the latter

```
<FONTMAP:/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2023.04.02:1712
mwe1.xdv -> mwe1.pdf
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant.pfb@19.93pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant.pfb/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant(Identity-H)
>
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)

No output PDF file written.
```

the same example compiles without problems on *TeX Live 2019/Debian* and *TeX Live 2020/Debian*.

Replacing `JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant.pfb` by `ASCII.pfb` yields similar errors. So it seems not to be a problem with the specific font. Also, if I use "old-school" font selection as in LaTeX, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\begin{document}

\Fontskrivan ABCDEFG

\end{document}
```

Now I am wondering, am I doing something wrong and I was only lucky that it worked previously, is this a regression, or are Type 1 fonts no longer supported?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can install FontForge and convert the font: https://fontforge.org/docs/faq.html#faq-outline-conversion

Comment: on windows it works.

Comment: It works on my (somewhat old) mac os with TeXLive 2023.  Only had to change the path of course. Only thing is that log contains `Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/aurical/JanaSkrivanaBoldSlant.pfb]/OT:language=dflt;!`.  Both on TL2019 and TL2023.

Comment: The advice about converting (using FontForge) has the advantage that it is most likely to be future-proof. And the observation about missing U+0020 is critical, since that is the space character. If you do a font conversion, be sure to add a space character of likely width.